# Recovering dropped stash 'is not a stash-like commit'

Tags: git, version-control

I was attempting to recover a dropped stash with work I needed, following the many examples (such as [here](http://inlehmansterms.net/2015/09/19/recover-a-dropped-git-stash/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/7f0f1402f05c45bac10814a9e38f81bf) ) of

`git log --graph --oneline --decorate $(git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}')`

I found the hash ref (1234ABC) to the dangling commit I dropped and needed:

```
1234ABC untracked files on feature/guards: 0987XYZ Merge branch 'develop'
0987XYZ Merge branch 'develop'
```

but when I tried `git stash apply 1234ABC` I kept getting the following message:

```
'1234ABC' is not a stash-like commit
```

> I also noticed that if I checked out this reference into a detached HEAD branch, `git checkout -b 1234ABC`, the only log info available was a commit alone which only contained the changes made and stashed back then -- without any previous ancestral history.

So I tried this from a [Dev.to](https://dev.to/meduzen/recover-a-lost-git-stash-in-two-steps-569) article to try and update the stash refs, but then trying to pop/apply the stash there also failed to apply. This also brought other issues like not being able to drop the added stash "My recovered stash".

`git update-ref refs/stash 4b3fc45c94caadcc87d783064624585c194f4be8 -m "My recovered stash"`

---

#### Q1: What does the 'is not a stash-like commit' really mean?

#### Q2: Why did this happen, and how could I apply this stash properly?

> Will writing this, I tried `git stash apply 0987XYZ` (thinking more about how my dropped stash reference only had the stashed changes without any ancestral history and how these were untracked files, stashed when on the then current, referenced commit `0987XYZ`).
>
> I think it is similar to the solution written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831689/retrieve-a-deleted-stash-that-is-not-a-stash-like-commit), but there is really no educational value in the solution posted by the original poster, so...

#### Q3: In this case, would `git stash apply 0987XYZ`, applying the stash ref that of the parent (or previous) commit I needed, the proper way to do this?

Thanks for any insights and additional information to further educate me about this scenario!

Answer (score 2):

Git implements a stash as *two* commits, in order to be able to separately store the staged and the unstaged changes. If you use `-u` or `-a`, a *third* commit is created to store the untracked files (thanks to @torek for clearing up my confusion about this). The commit structure looks like this:

```
*__ Unstaged changes
|\ \
| | * Untracked files
| |
| * Staged changes
|/
* Base commit
```

So the commit that you have found is probably the parentless "untracked files" part of your stash. `git stash` presumably only knows how to work with the topmost "unstaged part" since that's the one that knows where the other parts are. If the changes you see in the commit you found are the ones you want, you could try to simply copy the files in it (this will *overwrite* any uncommitted changes to those files if they're currently in your working directory):

```
git checkout 1234ABC -- fileA fileB fileC
```

In order to identify the "unstaged changes" commit, you can look for a commit that has `1234ABC` as one of its parents. If you find it, you should be able to unstash it.

Comment: As far as I know, the `i` and `w` commits in a stash have always had the then-HEAD commit as one of their parents (`w` is a merge with two parents, `i` is a simple commit with one parent). There is an optional third commit holding `-u` or `-a` files and that third commit is parentless, and of course you can accidentally find the `i` commit instead of the `w` commit when looking for commits by commit message (both `i` and `w` have similar messages).

Comment: In this case, the message says "untracked files" in it so I think the OP has found a `u` commit. He needs the `w` commit.

Comment: @torek: Ah, that's probably what I've sometimes seen before - I just tried `-u`, and it did what you said. Updated my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is create a new branch from that commit, then cherry pick it into your current working branch.

```
git branch <new_branch_name> <hashCode>
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831708/4364358